# Product quantity based coupon rules for a single category products

Tags: php, drupal-7, ubercart, discount, coupon

I am working on drupal 7.12. I need to add a quantity based coupon for a single category products.

If I have that category product qty = 3 in cart and I apply the code it should apply on this category of product only.

I want to apply "buy 1 at $10, buy 2 at $15 and buy 6 at $30".

Please help how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called discount alternative module may do your targets. But it has only alpha version with critical bugs

https://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt

https://drupal.org/comment/7164268#comment-7164268